# Container for multiple controls in xaml

Tags: silverlight, xaml, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a custom control for a silverlight app that will basically allow the user to click and drag on a canvas and draw a line with a small rectangle at each end.  How can I encapsulate these three controls into one custom control.  I want to do something like this...

```
<UserControl x:Class="Linecontrol"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SomeAbstractGroupingContainer>
         <Line Name="ctlLine" /> 
         <Rectangle Name="rec1" />
         <Rectangle Name="rec2" />
    </SomeAbstractGroupingContainer>     
</UserControl>
```

Any idea what I could use for SomeAbstractGroupingContainer?

Comment: Moreover, how can I encapsulate this type of functionality in a single user control (using xaml for binding) to be drawn on a canvas (and later resized or moved) along with other similar compound controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx)?

Comment: I need none of the functionality of Canvas.  That's why I'd like to find some abstract container or some other solution.

Comment: That's hard to tell from the question, since you seem to be drawing on it (lines and rectangles.)  Maybe ItemsControl is more appropriate in your case?

Comment: I ended up having to use canvas and just handling the resizing of my controls and the Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure if this is the right approach for a drawing app (Noticed jlew's [Anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8301974/265165)?), I'll just answer your question, and hope you will find your solution.

The `ItemsControl` is the base control which is able to do this:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <Line Name="ctlLine" /> 
        <Rectangle Name="rec1" />
        <Rectangle Name="rec2" />
    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

This should work... so you could derive from `ItemsControl`:

```
public class SomeAbstractGroupingContainer : ItemsControl
{
    public SomeAbstractGroupingContainer()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(SomeAbstractGroupingContainer);
    }
}
```

And you could extend it as you wish.

So finally you end up with something like this:

```
<myControls:SomeAbstractGroupingContainer>
    <myControls:SomeAbstractGroupingContainer.Items>
        <Line Name="ctlLine" /> 
        <Rectangle Name="rec1" />
        <Rectangle Name="rec2" />
    </myControls:SomeAbstractGroupingContainer.Items>
</myControls:SomeAbstractGroupingContainer>
```

You can change the way the Items are arranged by modifying the `ControlTemplate`.

This was inspired by the [ItemsControl from scratch to your own controls](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/ItemsControl-from-scratch-to-your-own-controls.aspx) article, it might be helpful.

Comment: My problem with using a canvas is that I am already using a canvas on which many of this and other controls will be drawn on. These controls will all be resizable, which means I'd have to rezize the canvas's as well.

Comment: I notice the itemsControl has some layout/flow behavior (ala stack or dock panel) this won't work for me.  I need just a logical container with no real UI component.

Comment: @PhilBrown You actually don't have to have your items stacked. You should be able to override the `ItemsPanelTemplate` like this: `<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel><ItemsPanelTemplate><Canvas Name="CanvasItemsHost" /></ItemsPanelTemplate></ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>` (Add this to my first code example within `<ItemsControl>` and `</ItemsControl>`)

Comment: Is that not just using a Canvas?

Comment: @PhilBrown it's very similar, but you could have a dynamic (non-hardoded) collection of sub-controls which you could data-bind. But i see your problem is solved anyway :)